# vim multiple specific mappings

Tags: vim, vimrc

What is the best way to specify multiple modes for a map in vim?

---

I know that `nmap x y` triggers y on receiving x when in `normal mode`,

`imap x y` triggers y on receiving x when in `insert mode`, and so on.

Say I specifically want those two modes. Then I can not use `map x y`.

Just writing two lines produces a lot of clutter when done for multiple mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `:h mapmode-n`:

> There are six sets of mappings
>
> - For Normal mode: When typing commands.
> - For Visual mode: When typing commands while the Visual area is highlighted.
> - For Select mode: like Visual mode but typing text replaces the selection.
> - For Operator-pending mode: When an operator is pending (after "d", "y", "c",
>     etc.).  See below: |omap-info|.
> - For Insert mode.  These are also used in Replace mode.
> - For Command-line mode: When entering a ":" or "/" command.

There are many different ways to make a mapping. If you `:h map`, you will see which modes the various commands map modes for:

```
:map    {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-nvo|       *:map*
:nm[ap] {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-n|     *:nm* *:nmap*
:vm[ap] {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-v|     *:vm* *:vmap*
:xm[ap] {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-x|     *:xm* *:xmap*
:smap   {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-s|         *:smap*
:om[ap] {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-o|     *:om* *:omap*
:map!   {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-ic|        *:map!*
:im[ap] {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-i|     *:im* *:imap*
:lm[ap] {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-l|     *:lm* *:lmap*
:cm[ap] {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-c|     *:cm* *:cmap*
```

As you can see, `:map` says `mapmode-nvo`, which stands for *normal, visual, and operator-pending* mode. That is the reason that `map x y` does not work in normal mode. Looking through this list, you can see how none of them have `mapmode-in`, so there is no one way to do this. So you will need to do `nmap x y` and `imap x y`. Or if you want it to apply to every mode, `map x y`, and `map! x y`.

> Just writing two lines produces a lot of clutter when done for multiple mappings.

If you're really doing lots of mappings, you could do this:

```
function! DoubleMap(x, y)
  exec "nmap ".x." ".y
  exec "imap ".x." ".y
endfunction
```

Then

```
imap x y
nmap x y
imap foo bar
nmap foo bar
imap blah spam
nmap blah spam
```

Becomes

```
call DoubleMap('x', 'y')
call DoubleMap('foo', 'bar')
call DoubleMap('blah', 'spam')
```

But this will be a pain if your mapping has quotes or unprintable characters.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Too bad that there exists no mapmode for this combination. It seems like I will have to learn more about vimscript in general at this point. Using a function seems like a good option for simple binds.

Comment: @omnesia Glad I could help! :) BTW, there is also a [vi & vim site](https://vi.stackexchange.com) that is generally better for vim-specific questions.